# Issue with SelectOption not working

Tags: visualforce

I have a multiselect where I have seleted some fields and need to move same to other multiselect  I have a button add to add them and I am calling a method on the button click and checking the selected values from the multipicklist but it is displaying null. But on the same page I do have a single select dropdown for that it works good and get the selected value to the ctrl. I do have a action support for single select picklist but no action support for multiselect pick list only after select I am clicking on the button and checking it. Do you have any idea what is getting wrong out here.
In my debug also I can see the value is getting assigned and after that it reverted to null no idea what is happening that it reverted back to null. 
Debug log :

> 00:15:25.173 (173310326)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|filterScreen_ctrl set(FiledName,[location, durationinminutes, subject])
>   00:15:25.173 (173320674)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   00:15:25.173 (173330005)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|filterScreen_ctrl set(FiledName,[location, durationinminutes, subject])
>   00:15:25.173 (173385634)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|filterScreen_ctrl set(FiledName,[location, durationinminutes, subject])
>   00:15:25.173 (173396599)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|filterScreen_ctrl set(FiledName,[location, durationinminutes, subject])
>   00:15:25.173 (173419312)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|filterScreen_ctrl set(FiledName,null)
>   00:15:25.173 (173429069)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   00:15:25.173 (173437181)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|filterScreen_ctrl set(FiledName,null)
>   00:15:25.173 (173457180)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|filterScreen_ctrl set(FiledName,null)
>   00:15:25.173 (173465104)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|filterScreen_ctrl set(FiledName,null)
>   00:15:25.173 (173637492)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p90000005PIRR|filterScreen_ctrl invoke(addFields)

My VF page

```
<apex:page controller="filterScreen_ctrl" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >  

  <apex:actionFunction name="rightArrow" action="{!addFields}" reRender="selectionBlock"/>

   <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
           <apex:outputText value="Select Object : "></apex:outputText>
              <apex:selectList value="{!objectName}" size="1">
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!orgObjects}"/>
                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!RelatedFields}"/>
              </apex:selectList>
       </apex:pageBlockSection> 

       <br/><br/>
       <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!if(objectName != null, true, false)}" >
       <!--<apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!if(objectName != null, true, false)}" id="fieldPanal">   

          <apex:panelBar >
          <apex:panelBarItem label="Related Fields" >-->

          <!--<div id="container">-->

              <!--<div id="left">-->
                 <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                 <apex:outputText value="Available Fields"></apex:outputText><br/>

                 <apex:selectList value="{!FiledName}" size="6" id="fieldselst" multiselect="true"  >
                     <apex:selectOptions value="{!objFields}"/>

                      <!--
                      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!addFields}">
                           <apex:param id="addSelect" assignTo="{!objFields}" value="{!FiledName}" />
                      </apex:actionSupport>-->

                 </apex:selectList>

              <!--</div>-->

              <div id="middle" >
                  <apex:outputText value="ADD"></apex:outputText><br/>
                  <apex:commandButton action="{!addFields}" value=">>"  reRender="right"  > 
                  </apex:commandButton> 
                  <br/>
                  <apex:commandButton action="{!removeFields}" value="<<" /><br/>
                  <apex:outputText value="REMOVE"></apex:outputText>

              </div>

              <div id="right">
                  <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                  <apex:outputText value="Selected Fields"></apex:outputText><br/>

                  <apex:selectList value="{!FiledName}" size="6" >
                     <apex:selectOptions value="{!filterFields}"/>
                  </apex:selectList>

              </div>


         <!--</div>-->
         <!--</apex:panelBarItem>
         </apex:panelBar>   
          </apex:outputPanel>   --> 
          </apex:pageBlockSection >
   </apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
global class filterScreen_ctrl {

public Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
public String objectName {get; set;}
public String[] FiledName {get; set;}
//public String FiledName {get; set;}
public String[] holdSelectedFiledName {get; set;}
public String[] selFiledName {get; set;}
public List<Filter_Field_Set__c> FilterField_Lst {get; set;}
public List<String> selectedFieldname_lst {get; set;}

public Map<String, String> selectedFieldname_map {get; set;}
public String selectedFieldname ;
public String SelectedLayout {get; set;}

public filterScreen_ctrl (){

    FilterField_Lst = new List<Filter_Field_Set__c>();
    selectedFieldname_lst = new List<String>();
    selectedFieldname_map = new Map<String, String>();
    holdSelectedFiledName = new String[]{};
    //selFiledName = new String[]();
    //FiledName = new String[]{};   
}

public List<selectoption> getorgObjects(){

    List<SelectOption> option_obj = new List<SelectOption>();
    option_obj.add(new SelectOption('--Select--' , '--Select--'));
    for(String objectvalue: schemaMap.keyset()){
        option_obj.add(new SelectOption(objectvalue, schemaMap.get(objectvalue).getDescribe().getLabel()));
    }

    return option_obj;

}

public string RelatedFields(){

    FilterField_Lst = [SELECT Name, Object_Fields_Name__c FROM Filter_Field_Set__c WHERE Name = :objectName];

    for(integer i = 0; i <FilterField_Lst.size(); i++){
        selectedFieldname = string.valueof(FilterField_Lst[i].Object_Fields_Name__c);
        selectedFieldname_lst = selectedFieldname.split(',&,');
    }

    for(integer i=0; selectedFieldname_lst.size() > i; i++){
        selectedFieldname_map.put(selectedFieldname_lst[i], selectedFieldname_lst[i]);
    }   

    system.debug('Selected Field Name map ' + selectedFieldname_map);

    getfilterFields();
    getobjFields();
   return null;
}

public List<selectoption> getobjFields(){

    List<SelectOption> option_Obfield = new List<SelectOption>();
    Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    for(String sfield: fieldMap.keyset()){
        system.debug('Map contains ' + selectedFieldname_map.containsKey(sfield.trim()));
        system.debug('Select field ' + sfield);

        if(!selectedFieldname_map.containsKey(sfield.trim()))
            option_Obfield.add(new SelectOption(sfield , fieldMap.get(sfield).getDescribe().getLabel() ));
    }   

    system.debug('option Object field ' + option_Obfield);
    return option_Obfield;

}

public List<selectoption> getfilterFields(){

    List<SelectOption> option_Sfield = new List<SelectOption>();
    Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    for(integer i =0; selectedFieldname_lst.size() > i; i++){
        option_Sfield.add(new SelectOption(selectedFieldname_lst[i] , fieldMap.get(selectedFieldname_lst[i]).getDescribe().getLabel() ));
    }

    return option_Sfield;

}

//Radio Button
public List<selectoption> getLayout(){

    List<selectOption> option_layout = new List<selectOption>();
    option_layout.add(new selectOption('Filter_Field', 'Filter Field'));
    option_layout.add(new selectOption('Update_Field', 'Update Field'));        
    return option_layout;

}




public void addFields(){

    system.debug('Selected hold Selected Filed Name ' + holdSelectedFiledName);
    system.debug('Selected Filed Name ' + FiledName);


    //FiledName
    //selectedMlst = getFiledName();
   // return null;

}

public PageReference removeFields(){

    return null;    
}


}
```

Please do help me its is urgent. Got confused ..

Comment: You may be better off using this [Multiselect Picklist Visualforce Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/06/a-multiselect-picklist-visualforce-component.html) rather than building this from scratch as a few hundred lines of Visualforce/JavaScript/Apex are needed.

Comment: Anu -- sorry you are desperate but your cause would be improved if you a) reworded the question in much clearer, concise sentences with an illustration/example and b) (I may be wrong here) but you have variables named Filed and Field; the former looks like a common typo for 'field'